# Date serial number and date need to convert in date format

Tags: pandas

when I am reading google spreadsheet in dataframe getting data in below format

```
42836
42837
42838
42844
42845
42846
42849
42850
42851
2/1/2018
2/2/2018
```

But i need to convert all in date format

Comment: How to understand `42836` in normal time?

Comment: Days since some arbitrary date in 1900? I really don't know how anyone is supposed to figure this out without any more information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC setting up the `origin` date and using `np.where`, base on my experience 
the origin in Excel is December 30, 1899.

```
s1=pd.to_datetime(pd.to_numeric(df.date,errors='coerce'),errors='coerce',origin='1899-12-30',unit='D')
s2=pd.to_datetime(df.date,errors='coerce')
df['new']=np.where(df.date.str.contains('/'),s2,s1)
df
Out[282]: 
       date        new
0     42837 2017-04-12
1     42838 2017-04-13
2     42844 2017-04-19
3     42845 2017-04-20
4     42846 2017-04-21
5     42849 2017-04-24
6     42850 2017-04-25
7     42851 2017-04-26
8  2/1/2018 2018-02-01
9  2/2/2018 2018-02-02
```

Answer (score 0):

Use datetime with timedelta.
base year is 1.1.1900 then add the days as timedelta.
the for loop just shows the first three of your dates.
if you need a different format use strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())

```py
import datetime as dt
date = dt.datetime(1900,1,1)
dates = [42836, 42837, 42838]
for aDay in dates:<br>
    print(date+dt.timedelta(days=aDay))
```